# Multiple buttons sharing one event handler not functioning

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I'm having some difficulties getting my `EventHandler` working for multiple buttons. They will do the same job which is to link to the same form (`ModuleTemplate`) and populate it with the appropriate content that is relevant to that module.

I have only pasted the code in question. It all compiles fine and the first button (btnAudioNotetaker) works fine, the others do nothing.

```
public void createAudioNotetaker()
{
    //this button click event works
    btnAudioNotetaker.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => btnModule_Click(sender, e, audioNotetakerDict, videoPathDict, pdfPathDict, audioPathDict));
}

public void createClaroRead()
{
    //this one doesn't work
    btnClaroRead.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => btnModule_Click(sender, e, audioNotetakerDict, videoPathDict, pdfPathDict, audioPathDict));
}

void btnModule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, OrderedDictionary pageContent, OrderedDictionary videoPathDict, OrderedDictionary pdfPathDict, OrderedDictionary audioPathDict)
{
    //i want to use this event for each button
    ModuleTemplate newForm = new ModuleTemplate(pageContent, videoPathDict, pdfPathDict, audioPathDict);
    newForm.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Do you call _createClaroRead_ in your code? Is it executed?

Comment: Why does your method btnModule_Click have so many parameters? It is better to combine most of them into single class.

Comment: The parameters are there to handle the different content, paths, files, numbers, etc. There are quite a lot of elements that make up the ModuleTemplate form. Partly my lack of knowledge too! As for calling createClaroRead, I have wrapped each module's configuration like that as on some instances those modules will not be available to the user.

Comment: Silly question but have you put a break point inside `createClaroRead()` to ensure the method is being called? If that isn't being called then the issue lies outside of the code you have shown here.

Comment: You call btnModule_Click() with the *exact* same arguments, so you can't tell the difference.

Comment: @HansPassant - wouldn't sender be different depending on which button was pressed?

Comment: Sure, but he's not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas are cool and all but I think this code is clearer.  It may or may not fix your problem (you might get a compiler error when you try this code), but it will be much easier to maintain.

```
public void createAudioNotetaker()
{
    //this button click event works
    btnAudioNotetaker.Click += commonClickHandler;
}

public void createClaroRead()
{
    //this one doesn't work
    btnClaroRead.Click += commonClickHandler;
}

void commonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnModule_Click(sender, e, audioNotetakerDict, videoPathDict, pdfPathDict, audioPathDict));
} 

void btnModule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, OrderedDictionary pageContent, OrderedDictionary videoPathDict, OrderedDictionary pdfPathDict, OrderedDictionary audioPathDict)
{
    //i want to use this event for each button
    ModuleTemplate newForm = new ModuleTemplate(pageContent, videoPathDict, pdfPathDict, audioPathDict);
    newForm.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, as suggested in an above comment, I wasn't calling my createClaroRead function in my switch and case statements. Such a silly thing to overlook.

Thanks for the replies everyone.